# Elevation API for openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, elevation

Is there any Elevation API for openstreetmap like the one we have for google maps?
In google elevation API we can pass the coordinate and we get the elevation as a response.

Answer (score 16):

I've recently published [Open-Elevation](https://open-elevation.com), a free and open-source elevation API also available at Github. We offer a free public API and documentation on how to setup your own instance of the product.

It's also available on [Github](https://github.com/Jorl17/open-elevation).

Pull requests are welcome!

Comment: It is not clear what data is behind the public API.  Could you add that information?

Comment: Open-Elevation does not appear to work at the moment. Bit of a shame as it looked like a fantastic project. Spent the last couple of hours trying stuff and not even the public api seems to work :(

Comment: The service should be working much more reliably now.

Sadly, the service is widely used for free, but there is very little in the way of donations, so I have been unable to upgrade it properly to handle the load. A migration in the coming month (with more money coming out of my pocket each month) has made it available once more.

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap does not contain much elevation data.  https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/3069/elevation-maps

Comment: There are other public data sources that one can use though, like SRTM/CGIAR etc

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Open Topo Data](https://www.opentopodata.org/). It has a free and public API for different datasets, try e. g. for Europe with 25m resolution:

```
https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/eudem25m?locations=50.7827,6.0941|50.651,13.1469
```

This results in:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "dataset": "eudem25m",
      "elevation": 192.93936157226562,
      "location": {
        "lat": 50.7827,
        "lng": 6.0941
      }
    },
    {
      "dataset": "eudem25m",
      "elevation": 635.0579833984375,
      "location": {
        "lat": 50.651,
        "lng": 13.1469
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Python example with Pandas `DataFrame`. *The order must be latitude, longitude!*

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

# assuming you have lat/long coords in a DataFrame, maybe from geopandas
coords = pd.DataFrame([[53.66, 13.84],
                       [51.71, 13.76],
                       [48.75, 13.76],
                       [53.95, 13.81],
                       [50.94, 13.75]],
                      columns=['lat', 'long'])

# convert to a string for the request, like '53.66,13.84|51.71,13.76|...'
coords_str = coords.to_string(col_space=1, index=False, header=False)
coords_str = ",".join(coords_str.replace('\n', '|').split())

# query Open Topo Data using post request
url = "https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/eudem25m"
req_data = {"locations": coords_str, "interpolation": "bilinear"}
r = requests.post(url, data=req_data)
results = r.json()['results']

# add elevations to DataFrame
elevations = [res['elevation'] for res in results]
coords['elevations'] = elevations
print(coords)
```

Prints:

```
     lat   long  elevations
0  53.66  13.84    4.061932
1  51.71  13.76  144.021271
2  48.75  13.76  692.658936
3  53.95  13.81   23.207273
4  50.94  13.75  249.106003
```

For more than 100 locations, use chunking:

```py
results = []
for i, coords in tqdm(all_coords.groupby(all_coords.index // 100)):
    coords_str = ...
    ...
    results += r.json()['results']
```

To query a single location, see my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77179130/2414411).

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently working on a new open source elevation service **GeoPicker**, very high-performance and with an extensive and easy-to-use API for every case, written in Fastify and GDAL.
Among the next implementations there is an idea of integration with Openstreetmap Nodes [here](https://github.com/opengeo-tech/GeoPicker/issues/27)

here is the project page:
https://github.com/opengeo-tech/geopicker

and a detailed article:

https://stefcud.medium.com/geopicker-bf4c4321c9ec