# ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Tags: python, numpy-ufunc, pvlib

I am trying to run this script but it's showing generated error:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

This is the code below I am trying to run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Nominatim(user_agent="test_solar")

    loc_raw = app.geocode('Postintaival 7, 00230 Helsinki, Finland').raw

    latitude = loc_raw['lat']
    longitude = loc_raw['lon']
    altitude = get_elevation(latitude, longitude)

    location_object = Location(latitude, longitude, 'Europe/Helsinki', altitude,
                               'relex_solutions')

    weather = pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_tmy(latitude, longitude, map_variables=True)[0]

    times = weather.index

    solpos = location_object.get_solarposition(times)

    clearsky_values = location_object.get_clearsky(times, model='ineichen',
                                                   solar_position=solpos,
                                                   dni_extra=None)
```

Comment: Post the full traceback message so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

Convert your longitude (and also the latitude for consistency) to float and it will work:

```py
    latitude = float(loc_raw['lat'])
    longitude = float(loc_raw['lon'])
```

### Longer explanation

It takes some times to add all the import and missing function for having a minimum reproducible example. I guess that the `get_elevation` function is coming  from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513212/can-i-get-the-altitude-with-geopy-in-python-with-longitude-latitude).

```py
import requests
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from pvlib.location import Location
import pvlib
import pandas as pd


def get_elevation(lat, long):
    query = ('https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup'
             f'?locations={lat},{long}')
    r = requests.get(query).json()  # json object, various ways you can extract value
    # one approach is to use pandas json functionality:
    elevation = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r, 'results')['elevation'].values[0]
    return elevation


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Nominatim(user_agent="test_solar")

    loc_raw = app.geocode('Postintaival 7, 00230 Helsinki, Finland').raw

    latitude = loc_raw['lat']
    longitude = loc_raw['lon']
    altitude = get_elevation(latitude, longitude)

    location_object = Location(latitude, longitude, 'Europe/Helsinki',
                               altitude, 'relex_solutions')
    weather = pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_tmy(latitude, longitude,
                                          map_variables=True)[0]

    times = weather.index

    solpos = location_object.get_solarposition(times)
    clearsky_values = location_object.get_clearsky(times, model='ineichen',
                                                   solar_position=solpos,)
```

Here where your problem is coming in `pvlib.spa` module:

```py
@jcompile('float64(float64, float64, float64)', nopython=True)
def local_hour_angle(apparent_sidereal_time, observer_longitude,
                     sun_right_ascension):
    """Measured westward from south"""
    H = apparent_sidereal_time + observer_longitude - sun_right_ascension
    return H % 360
```

I added some print in order to see the variables (a debug point should also work):

```py
@jcompile('float64(float64, float64, float64)', nopython=True)
def local_hour_angle(apparent_sidereal_time, observer_longitude,
                     sun_right_ascension):
    """Measured westward from south"""
    print(f'{apparent_sidereal_time!r}')
    print(f'{observer_longitude!r}')
    print(f'{sun_right_ascension!r}')
    H = apparent_sidereal_time + observer_longitude - sun_right_ascension
    return H % 360
```

And we get:

```
array([100.06452967, 115.10559772, 130.14666594, ...,  55.20775781,
        70.24882694,  85.28989625])
'24.9181469'
array([280.83336392, 280.87939039, 280.92541462, ..., 280.99011537,
       281.03612276, 281.0821279 ])
```

The `observer_longitude` argument is a string which is not manage in numpy sum operation. After some exploration, I find that this longitude is directly coming from the `Location` object and thus the simple conversion of it into `float` solves the matter.